# Auto fit dynamic div block

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="test" style="width:40px;height:100px"><div>
    <div class="test" style="width:20px;height:150px;"><div>
    <div class="test" style="width:40px;height:100px;"><div>
    <div class="test" style="width:40px;height:100px;"><div>
</div>

.main{
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:140px;
    height:400px;
}
.test{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid silver;
    position:relative;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Div and its height and width are coming dynamically. I am trying to fit the div width in the layout .2 per on raw.
Please suggest.

Comment: Did you try to use some grid system? For example Bootstrap or some lighter version

Comment: yes i am using bootstrap

Comment: You can try using Masonry for this kind of layout.

Comment: @connexo Why did you changed the question? It'd be better to keep it as it was

Comment: What are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

The `height` of the container div should be `auto`. So, it'll take the optimal space to fit the inner elements.

```
.main {
    ...
    height: auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/7kyndy2a/1/)

```css
.main {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 140px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.test {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="test" style="width:40px;height:100px"></div>
  <div class="test" style="width:20px;height:150px;"></div>
  <div class="test" style="width:40px;height:100px;"></div>
  <div class="test" style="width:40px;height:100px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but still have empty spaces ,last row div has to fit

Comment: @prash Can you change the height of `main` div?

Comment: i mean by empty space is between first column divs ,may i need to use some jquery it seems ,thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

If you already use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) you can use its classes to make 2 items per row

https://jsfiddle.net/3mdrrjf8/1/

```
<div class="main row">
  <div class="test col-md-8 col-xs-6" style="height:100px"></div>
  <div class="test col-md-8 col-xs-6" style="height:150px;"></div>
  <div class="test col-md-8 col-xs-6" style="height:100px;"></div>
  <div class="test col-md-8 col-xs-6" style="height:100px;"></div>
</div>
```